# Как работать с Андроид ashmem?

Tags: android

Как работать с Андроид ashmem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы писать код, нужно подключить заголовок /linux/ashmem.h. Далее ход действий, например, следующий:

1. Открыть дескриптор `ASHMEM_NAME_DEF`.
2. Задать имя `ASHMEM_SET_NAME`.
3. Задать размер `ASHMEM_SET_SIZE`.
4. Отобразить память.
5. Использовать память.
6. Закрыть дескриптор.